# JS function is not defined for IE11

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-11

I did a javascript function to ajax calls (simpleRequest). This function is static, so there is not necessary to declare object.
This function works in Chrome, Firefox and Edge, but doesn't work in IE11.

I have an application that do ajax calls. But it's not work in IE11. I've seen this browser doesn't support class, but is there any way to solve this?

In main.php

```
...
var dataJsonVideo = {
    way: cam,
    kind: 'video'
};

var onsuccessVideo = function(response) {
    $('.list_tutorial > #id_tut_0').addClass("index_active_tutorial");
    $("#getTutorial").html(response);
}

JSHelper.simpleRequest(myDataTutorial, dataJsonVideo, "POST", onsuccessVideo);
```

In JSHelper.js

```
class JSHelper {

    static simpleRequest(urlSent, dataSent, typeSent, funcSuccess, funcBefore = '', params = '') {

    var jsonAjax = {};
    if(funcBefore != '')
        jsonAjax.beforeSend = funcBefore;
    jsonAjax.url = urlSent;
    jsonAjax.type = typeSent;
    jsonAjax.data = dataSent;
    if(params != '')
        for(var key in params)
            jsonAjax[key] = params[key];
    jsonAjax.success = funcSuccess;
    $.ajax(jsonAjax);
    }
}
```

The error is SCRIPT5009: 'JSHelper' is not defined.

Comment: Do you have <!DOCTYPE html> in your html?

Comment: IE11 does not support ES6 features other than keywords `const` and `let`. `class` is an ES6 feature.

Comment: IE11 does not support class https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/

Comment: Classes are [not supported](https://caniuse.com/#feat=es6-class) in IE.

Comment: According to this page http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/, ES6 features are not implemented in IE 11. Since `class` is part of ES6, maybe that's why it doesn't works

Comment: https://caniuse.com/#search=class is an easy way to check if stuff works in IE.

Comment: @connexo and if I recall, [it doesn't even implement `let` _correctly_](https://caniuse.com/#feat=let) (i.e. with correct lexical scope)

Comment: @jmargolisvt Though this would be the correct link: https://caniuse.com/#feat=es6-class

Comment: I put DOCTYPE html but it's not solved @KadeM.

Comment: Check the duplicate link. Only way to solve it is using a transpiler like ***babel***. Or rewrite the code which I assume is way beyond the scope of your current skill level.

Comment: I've seen the IE11 does not support class, but is there any way to solve this ?  @connexo

Comment: I mentioned it, the duplicate mentions it.

Comment: @connexo Rewrite the code is a problem, because it will be a lot of work. People talks about babel. Is it a plugin? How do I use to implementation?

Answer (score 3):

IE11 does not support es6 classes perhaps a tool like [babel](https://github.com/babel/babel) would help.
Also you can use this [tool](https://caniuse.com/#home) to check if you can use certain things on certain browsers.

Comment: how do I use babel?

Comment: everything you need to know is in the link to babel, you can click on it and it will take you to the babel github repo where you can find the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that "class" is not compatible with IE11, according to MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes